# Site takes longer time to load through .com domain but less through .net domain, why?

Tags: php, html

I am experiencing a weird issue. My site takes longer time to load through .com domain but the same site is fast when navigated through .net domain. What may be the cause of this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your name server configuration. If the root servers list a name server for the .com domain that is not answering it can lead to timeouts before another server is tried.

Another reason could be if yo have any kind of special handling for different host headers on your server.

Comment: could you tell me where should I check that ?